# Convergence of series with complex exponentials

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, complex-numbers

Suppose that $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R}/2\pi\mathbb{Z})$ takes the form $$f(\theta)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_ne^{in\theta}.$$ If $z=re^{i\theta}=x+iy$, $$F(z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty r^na_ne^{in\theta}$$ is a harmonic function in $|z|<1$.

But why does the series for $F(z)$ converge for $|z|<1$?

Comment: It doesn't necessarily; that depends on what exactly $a_n$ is.  However, the ratio-test applies, even if the terms are complex-valued.

Comment: You forgot to substitute $z=e^{i n \theta }$ in F(z).

Comment: @Omnomnomnom $a_n$ is the coefficients from the above series of $f(\theta)$, where $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R}/2\pi\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: I suppose then that we assume $f(\theta)$ actually converges and that the series is not merely formal.  In that case, we know that $\lim_{n\to \infty} |a_{n+1}/a_n| \leq 1$, and we may use that knowledge to apply the ratio-test for convergence to $F(z)$.

Comment: Try to work out the problem of finding the radius of convergence of series. You need to check the definition of $a_n$.

Comment: I mean $z=re^{i\theta}$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Yeah, I think we can assume $f(\theta)$ actually converges. Still, don't we have to worry that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}|a_{n+1}/a_n|$ might not exist?

Comment: Ah, that's a fair point.  You could look at the limsup and liminf, but I don't think that necessarily takes care of it.  I'm not sure where to go from there, actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Parseval, the coefficients $a_n$ are square-summable. Consequently, they are bounded. Hence, the series defining $F$ converges by comparison to the geometric series $\sum  r^n$.

Furthermore, the convergence is uniform on compact subsets of the disk.

Furthermore, if the series for $F$ is differentiated term-wise, the convergence persists. You can use this justify the fact that the sum is a smooth function with zero Laplacian. (Although it's easier to write each term as real part of a holomorphic function   and appeal to the fact that locally uniform convergence preserves holomorphicity;  the latter follows from Morera's theorem.)